# Extension failing to remove some pages on google "Images" tab on results page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am creating an extension that allows a user to save some tags(pages) and when they search google, the extension checks storage and filters out these tags from the result. Currently I am able to remove these tags from the 'All' tab but the code is not working on the 'Images' tab.

- How am checking type of search

```
function isImgSearch{
     if (window.location.pathname.includes("/images") || 
       window.location.href.includes("&tbm=isch")) {
       return true;
  }else{return false}
}
```

- I am iterating through all search results using the following line to remove the pages

```
const searchResults = document.querySelectorAll('.g');
```

- My mutation observer

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(removeUnwantedResults);
observer.observe(document.body, { subtree: true, childList: true });
```

How do I tackle filtering out the tags from both the 'All' & 'Images' tab? Thanks